# Why is onclick unable to access the function it is calling?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an async function that dynamically generates a pop-up window with information about the item selected as well as a button to close the same pop-up window.

```
const displayTvShowDetails = (tvShow) => {
  const tvShowInfo = document.getElementById('tv-show-details');
  tvShowInfo.classList.add('popup-container');
  tvShowInfo.innerHTML = ` 
    <div class="tv-show-details-container">
...lots of tv-show info here that is irrelevant to this post
        <div>
          <button id="close-window" onclick="closeTvShowDetails()" >Close Window</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
  `;
};
```

As you can see, the button's `onclick` attribute calls the `closeTvShowDetails()` function (this is a webpacked project but the named function resides in the same file as the button that calls it).

```
const closeTvShowDetails = () => {
  const popup = document.getElementById('tv-show-details');
  popup.style.display = 'none';
};
```

This is the error message I get:

```
closeTvShowDetails is not defined
ReferenceError: closeTvShowDetails is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I have created several projects such as this one before and implemented exactly the same functionality in them. There must be something that I am not seeing despite looking at the code and testing it repeatedly. Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Top-level `const` and `let` values are not promoted to `global` properties, only `var` variables (and `function`-style functions) are. Either change `displayTvShowDetails` to `var` or `function`

Comment: There's no reason for the function to be async.

Comment: @Andy You're right. It doesn't need to be. I've gone ahead and corrected that. The problem, however, persists.

Comment: Thank you @Dai. I made attempts by changing `displayTvShowDetails` to var and then to a function and I continue getting the same error message.

Comment: As Dai suggests change the function expressions to function declarations. Are those functions both in the same file? (Note: I just tested the code and it does work).

Comment: @German Sorry, I meant you should change `closeTvShowDetails`, not `displayTvShowDetails`